# Checking if a username or email exists in the DB already

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation

I want to check if the username of email already exists in the DB when a user signs up to my website.
I have the following code which isn't working and i'm not sure why. If anyone could point me in the right direction to validate against already existing info in the DB I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    WHERE username = '". $username ."' 
        OR email = '". $email ."'"
);

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    die ('Username or email already in use.');
}
```

Comment: "Isn't working" isn't concrete enough to make educated guesses about where it fails. Elaborate on input, table structure and content, turn on error_reporting, add print_r statements etc., and use proper database escaping.

Comment: Please print_r($query);

Comment: I have error_reporting on but there is no error being outputted.

Comment: So, the inference is that `mysql_num_rows($query)` is zero.  What's in $username and $email?  Are these in the DB?

Comment: Sidenote: The original `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_MySQL`. Plus; make sure you've escaped `$username` and `$email` before inserting them in a query to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: What i want to happen is have the username and email that the user signing up to the site enters into the forms, Validated against the  already existing info in the DB. If there is a match kill the script and output an error. I have escaped all variables to protect against sql injection

Comment: so you need to chsange the 'die()' to output an error?

Comment: We can't help you unless we know about the data.  (Have you taken into account that comparisons are case sensitive, for example?)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing the username field as a primary key or unique.

Or run the sql

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE username='$php_username_var';
```

Comment: I have the ID field set as unique, Can i set more than one field to unique?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following code, this is being used on the sign up page of my site, I hope you get your answer.

```
$sq="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
 $rsult=mysql_query($sq);      $count=mysql_num_rows ($rsult); 
if($count==1){echo "username already in use"; }

else 

{

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, password, sex, place)
VALUES('$username', '$password', '$sex', '$place')"; } 
$result=mysql_query($sql);     if($result)
{header("location:home.php"); }
else 
{ echo "Error, please go back and sign up again! "; }  ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this and adapted it to my DB info but it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the error message